# windows interrupt dispatching

Tags: windows

lets assume the I'am currently running a user mode application and an  hardware interrupt occurs
from window internals the dispatching process is :

1) when the proccesor gets an interupt signal from the PIC it queres the controller to get the interrupt request (IRQ).

2) The interrupt controller translates the IRQ to an interrupt number, use dispatch table (IDT), and transfers control to the appropriate interrupt dispatch routine.

my question is in which context the interrupt dispaching routine get executed?

if their is process context switch when it occures ?

i know that software interupt (APC/DPC) handling take place at the interupted process context.

Comment: No process switch is involved.  This code runs in kernel mode, the interrupt handler is in a driver.  The mode transition from ring 3 to ring 0 is part of the interrupt handling.

Comment: @HansPassant: related question - if the driver's interrupt handler does something that makes a waiting high priority process runnable, and assuming a single CPU core, does a process switch occur immediately, or only at the next timeslice?